# How to disable autocompletion of function signatures in spyder

Tags: spyder

When typing a function in the Spyder editor, such as  `fcn(`, I find that Spyder often automatically barfs the entire function signature into the editor. This is especially unhelpful when instantiating a dataclass object--Spyder evidently still cannot read the dataclass fields--and even less helpful when using annotations, which I do frequently. How do I disable this feature? I'm using Spyder 4.1.1.

Comment: How did you install Spyder, Anaconda or pip?

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:
In `Tools > Preferences > Completion and Linting > Advanced`  and disable `Enable fallback completions` and `Enable code completion`

Or in `Tools > Preferences > Editor > Code introspection`  and uncheck what options you don't want.

Comment: This gets me close, but it seems to do something with snippets.